# using linq-like expression in angular ng-show

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, linq

I have an array of trades:

```
var trades = [
    {
        orders: [
            {
                confirmed: true
            },
            {
                confirmed: false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I would like to use a linq-like expression in my directive expression (in this case an ng-hide):
So, something like (warning: hybrid c#-angular code below):

```
<div ng-repeat="trade in trades">
      <span ng-hide="trade.orders.any(order => !order.confirmed)">Confirmed</span>
</div>
```

is there any way to write the `.any(order => !order.confirmed)` using javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular doesn't have this, but there are some libraries you can use alongside it which provide LINQ-like features, including `.any()`:

- https://lodash.com/
- http://underscorejs.org/

Answer (score 4):

This may be a little late, but using a filter you can achieve this.

```
<div ng-repeat="trade in trades">
    <span ng-hide="(trade.orders | filter:{'confirmed':true}).length === 0">Confirmed</span>
</div>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 2):

I am the creator of jinqJs. http://www.jinqjs.com 
Here is a Plunker demo of is used with angularJs http://plnkr.co/edit/UXIYLA?p=info

The .where() excepts a * for contains, if that helps you

```
             jinqJs()
                .from(people)
                .where( 'Location * Melville')
                .groupBy('Location', 'Condition').avg('Age')
                .select([{field: 'Location'}, {field: 'Age', text: 'Average Age'}, {field: 'Condition'}]);
```

Comment: How would you go about adding this to an angularJs module

Comment: Just add the jinqJs.js reference to your html page. You can then use jinqJs inside your controller or service.

Comment: Thank you :-).  Got it working.   This is pretty sweet!